# Below what threshold of intensity can a ray of light be considered absorbed?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, absorption, intensity

Say I have a beam of light of intensity I. I'm modeling its traversal through a medium which absorbs light. As it travels, I reduce its strength by a certain specified factor. Below what intensity should it be considered absorbed? I/10 or I/100 etc? How should this be determined?

The beam in question has a wavelength of 450nm and is travelling through a transparent thin plastic, but I would like to attenuate it in order to determine the amount or intensity of light reaching a certain portion of the plastic.

Comment: That depends entirely on *why you care*. What do you want to happen or not happen?

Comment: @dmckee I want to collect photons that reach a certain area in the plastic (that is connected to a silicon photomultiplier for photon collection). I'm wondering if there's a threshold light at different energies which can be considered absorbed in a media once its below a certain intensity?

Comment: You could use whatever threshold you like, or whatever threshold is meaningful to the people who will read your results.

Comment: Rather than say the beam is absorbed when $1/10$ of it is, say the beam is $10$% absorbed.